# How can I read input from a text file in Perl?

Tags: perl

I would like to take input from a text file in Perl. Though lot of info are available over the net, it is still very confusing as to how to do this simple task of printing every line of text file. So how to do it? I am new to Perl, thus the confusion .

Comment: You should get a book and study the language methodically. See http://learn.perl.org/

Comment: @Sinan There is a [stackoverflow question about perl books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336715/what-are-good-books-for-learning-perl).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, open the file:

```
open my $fh, '<', "filename" or die $!;
```

Next, use the `while` loop to read until EOF:

```
while (<$fh>) {
    # line contents's automatically stored in the $_ variable
}
close $fh or die $!;
```

Answer (score 4):

eugene has already shown the proper way. Here is a shorter script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
print while <>
```

or, equivalently,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
```

on the command line:

```
perl -pe0 textfile.txt
```

You should start learning the language methodically, following a decent book, not through haphazard searches on the web.

You should also make use of the extensive documentation that comes with Perl.

See <kbd>perldoc perltoc</kbd> or [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/).

For example, opening files is covered in [perlopentut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html).

Comment: That would need to be `perl -p -e0 textfile.txt` or `perl -p /dev/null textfile.txt` or similar to keep either stdin or textfile.txt from being treated as the perl program to run.

Comment: If you don't want to put the filename on the command line, I will often hardcode in quick n dirty scripts: @ARGV="filename.txt"; You can also put the "-p" or a "-n" on the shebang (e.g., #!/usr/bin/perl -p) line.

Answer (score 2):

```
# open the file and associate with a filehandle
open my $file_handle, '<', 'your_filename'
  or die "Can't open your_filename: $!\n";

while (<$file_handle>) {
  # $_ contains each record from the file in turn
}
```

Comment: @jm666 Thanks. I got halfway through fixing that a month ago and then completely forgot about it. Fixed now.

Comment: @HiginioFuentes: You should probably post this as a question - including a runnable version of your code.

Answer (score -1):

Despite of the fact that Perl have many ways to do the things, this one is ok:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = "nombres-sin.txt";
open(FH, "<nombres-sin.txt") or die "Not open $filename or$!";
while(<FH>) {
    print "$_";
}
close(FH) or die "No puedo cerrar! or $!";
```

Comment: This answer repeats what has already been posted, but using the old Perl 4 style of doing things.

Comment: @briandfoy, my version goes like a charm, the other one is not running correctly.